# $\int_{a}^{b}f(x+\sin n)dx\geq\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ implies $f(a)=f(b).$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and $a,b,a<b$ such that $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x+\sin n)dx\geq{\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx}$$
>   for any positive integer $n$. Prove that $f(a)=f(b)$.

I could at most say that $f(x+\sin n)\geq f(x)$ for all $x\in[a,b]$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ from the given information. But how can it help to get me $f(a)=f(b)$ I don't understand. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $\sin n$ is dense in $[-1,1]$ so you could see if you can make the conclusion obtained by replacing $\sin n$ above by $t \in [-1,1]$.

Comment: $a,b$ are arbitrary, why should it be specified to $[-1,1]$ only?

Comment: What values can $\sin$ take?

Comment: How can you conclude that$f(x+\sin n) \ge f(x)$?

Comment: Possibly consider my comment, small $t$ and the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 4):

The sequence $n \mapsto \sin n$ is dense in $[-1,1]$, in particular we can find subsequences $s_n \uparrow 0$ and $t_n \downarrow 0$.

Note that $\int_a^b f(x+v) dt = \int_{a+v}^{b+v} f(x) dx$.

$\int_{a+s_n}^{b+s_n} f(x)dx- \int_a^b f(x)dx = \int_{a+s_n}^{a} f(x)dx - \int_{b+s_n}^{b} f(x)dx \ge 0$. Dividing across by $-s_n$ and letting $n \to \infty$ gives
$f(a) \ge f(b)$.

A similar analysis with the positive sequence $t_n$ gives $f(b) \ge f(a)$.